# how to play youtube video uploaded from asp.net website?

Tags: asp.net

My asp.net code can upload video successfully. Now I want the url of that video and want to play that video with embed youtube player. 
pleasee help me..
thanks in advance

Comment: if you have the video file, then you can not set youtube to play it. Find an video flash player to play it.

Answer (score 0):

Embedded YouTube player is there to play youtube videos. In this case initially your video should be uploaded to youtube prior to embedding it to the player. For this you may have to use the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet)